# Using PC scores in PCA

Tags: pca

This might be a basic question, but I am analysing the diversity of floral traits in plant communities. Some of my data are reflectance spectra. I want to reduce the complexity of these data by doing PCA on the spectra, and then include those PC axis scores in another PCA including other morphological traits.

Is it problematic to use PC scores in a PCA? Are any issues e.g. of circularity likely to be encountered?

Comment: The success of PCA is how far it produces PCs that are interesting or useful. Provided you are alive to the possibility of circularity, as you are, there is no absolute barrier to using those PCs in another analysis, and many people do this. I've a preference personally for using PCA to illuminate which of several original variables should be carried forward, an approach occasionally automated as principal variables analysis. e.g. Cumming, J.A. and Wooff, D.A. 2007. Dimension reduction via principal variables. Computational Statistics & Data Analysis 52: 550-565.

Comment: This sounds almost like a second order PCA. As @NickCox says, there  is not necessarily a problem with this.

Answer (score 1):

I would think it is OK to do that, but you must be careful about two issues:
1) make sure your variables for the first PCA have same direction so that the PCs are representative of the spectra. In another words, all of variables for reflectance spectra should be either recorded from low to high or high to low. If the directions are mixed you still can do the second PCA but the PCs from first PCA are trouble in explanation.

2) Check how large of the total variance of spectra can be explained by the first 1 or 2 PCs. The larger of the proportion, the better for the second PCA. If the proportion is small, it may be not suitable to use these PCs for the second PCA.